# Is there a use case for this type of memory management?

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

I found this piece of code in Reddit's "learnprogramming" sub ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/5no1zd/whats_your_favorite_piece_of_code_youve_come/dcd3wft/)).

The author claims that it is optimal for some undeclared use case. But I can't personally think of one. I tend to agree with some of the other posters who commented that this looks suspiciously like dynamic memory allocation, except it's done inside an object of fixed size, rather than on the system heap. But I'm willing to keep an open mind and consider that maybe I've overlooked a strange use case.

So, is there actually a use case for this type of object, where "parking cars" (allocating objects) inside it would be better than allocating them directly on the runtime stack or heap?

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
class CarPark {

  public:
    CarPark() {
      // Setup initial free spaces
      for (size_t i = SIZE; i > 0; --i) {
        mFreeSpaces.push(i - 1);
      }
    }

    const size_t& Park(const T* const t) {
      size_t ticket = mFreeSpaces.top();
      mSpaces.at(ticket) = t;
      mFreeSpaces.pop();
      return ticket;
    }

    const T* const DePark(size_t ticket) {
      const T* const result = mSpaces.at(ticket);
      mSpaces.at(ticket) = nullptr;
      mFreeSpaces.push(ticket);
      return result;
    }

  private:
    std::array<const T*, SIZE> mSpaces { { nullptr } };
    std::stack<size_t> mFreeSpaces;

};
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you to think about this if you replaced `const T*` with `int` mentally.

Comment: Besides the `std::stack`, using a fixed size with resizing within that space is useful for `constexpr` functions. For example, a stack with max size can be used in `constexpr`.

Comment: This is actually nothing like dynamic memory allocation.  It's just a way of turning pointers into size_ts and back.  In the author's case it was so he could send the size_t over the wire, get it back, and lookup the object with it.  It's a good solution for that problem. (although there should really be more safety checks)

Answer (score 1):

CarPark pre-allocates a constant number of *contiguous* bytes for spaces.
I can see at least two use cases:

1> Spacial locality: ... at least for the spaces for the cars (see the comment) If CarPark put cars in the spaces directly, the following benefits might be available: instead of having your cars stored in pseudo-random locations in the heap memory space, all cars will be packed together tightly, which means that iterating over all cars or freeing the memory space will be quick. This will lickly be cache friendly.

2> Possible multi-threaded applications: from my understanding the default allocator is not very friendly for multi-programming (correct me if I am wrong. I base this point on my experience with C.) The allocator has to wait for individual memory requests to be completed before taking any other requests, so if you wanted to use multiple threads to park certain cars, there would be no point. Since all allocation is done beforehand, multiple threads could park cars (of course you'd have to implement necessary multi-threading-safe sections) and not wait for the allocator to finish requests.

3> See the comment:

> In the case where allocation overhead is significant, managing fixed
>   size elements locally can be more efficient.
>   en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation - Rich

In the ideal case, you would know how many cars on average (or exactly) the program would need to park. That way there would be no memory waste.

These are just my thoughts though. I am curious to see other answers as well.

Comment: In the case where allocation overhead is significant, managing fixed size elements locally can be more efficient.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation

Comment: There's spatial locality in the "spaces" for the "cars", but not with the "cars".  `CarPark` does not allocate any `T` objects so the benefits you list under (1) are not available.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Does my edit adequately reflect what you said? Feel free to edit my answer.